# Can this solution to "Contains Duplicate" be done more Pythonically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a solution to the LeetCode problem "Contains Duplicate". I tried using `enumerate(nums[1:])` instead of `range(1, len(nums))`, but I couldn't figure out how to do the equivalent of this in a concise and clear way due to enumerate always starting at 0.

```
class Solution:
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        nums.sort()
        
        pointer2 = 0
                
        for pointer1 in range(1, len(nums)):
            if nums[pointer1] == nums[pointer2]:
                return True
            pointer2 = pointer1
            
        return False
```

Comment: "due to enumerate always starting at 0" - you should really check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: The correct answer is setting the start parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use sets. We know that a set can not have repeating values, so when we cast a list of integers to a set, it removes duplicates. Then all we have to do is compare the two lengths. Try this:

```
return len(set(nums)) == len(nums)
```

Comment: This does produce a correct answer to the question, but I wanted to use the same algorithm as in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This can be written like so

```
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        nums.sort()
        
        pointer2 = 0
            
        for pointer1, num in enumerate(nums[1:], start=1):
            if num == nums[pointer2]:
                return True
            pointer2 = pointer1
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple one line solution, i would suggest you to go through all the data structures in Python first then attempt questions there.

you should use set instead of two pointers:

```
class Solution(object):
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
        return len(nums) != len(set(nums))
```

another way would be to use Hashmaps:

```
    hashNum = {}
    for i in nums:
         if i not in hashNum:
             hashNum[i] = 1
         else:
             return True
    return False
```